# How do I write blue text for Delphi that deletes as soon as you start typing

Tags: delphi-7

I need to write blue text on an edit so that it deletes as soon as I start typing on it when it run.
Please can you help me with how that works. This is for Delphi 2007

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is actually very easy, just select the text. There are various ways to do that, as you can see in the answer of Remy. Please use that answer and not the accepted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of my head, not tested:

- Use a standard TEdit.
- Set a boolean variable (flag) to TRUE.
- Write blue text in TEdit.
- Set edit cursor on first position
- In the OnKeyDown, if the flag is true then set the flag as false and delete the text in edit

Comment: One of the other things I tried that worked was writing the text in the edit. Then setting edt.clear in the onclick property

Comment: This answer doesn't make a lot of sense. There's literally nothing that the programmer needs to do. The system does it. No flags necessary. Just select the text in the edit control. That's it.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a bit ambiguous.  It could be interpreted in a couple of different ways.

You could *select* the current text, so that subsequent user input will replace the selection.  You do that in a standard [`TEdit`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.StdCtrls.TEdit) using its [`SelStart`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.StdCtrls.TCustomEdit.SelStart)/[`SelLength`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.StdCtrls.TCustomEdit.SelLength) properties, [`AutoSelect`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.StdCtrls.TCustomEdit.AutoSelect) property, or [`SelectAll()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.StdCtrls.TCustomEdit.SelectAll) method.  You might also consider setting its [`HideSelection`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.StdCtrls.TCustomEdit.HideSelection) property to false, if you want the highlight to be visible when the `TEdit` does not have input focus.

Or, you might be thinking of a "Cue Banner", which is a feature introduced in XP to display hint text inside of an edit control whenever it does not contain actual text.  You can set this hint text in a standard `TEdit` by sending it an [`EM_SETCUEBANNER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/em-setcuebanner) window message via the Win32 API [`SendMessage()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendmessage) function or [`Edit_SetCueBannerText()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/nf-commctrl-edit_setcuebannertext) macro (in Delphi 2009 and later, `TEdit` has a [`TextHint`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.StdCtrls.TCustomEdit.TextHint) property for this purpose).  Note that you need to [enable Visual Styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/cookbook-overview) in your application for this feature to work.